# How do you use matrices in Nimrod?

Tags: math, matrix, nim-lang

I found [this](https://github.com/twist-vector/matrix) project on GitHub; it was the only search term returned for "nimrod matrix". I took the bare bones of it and changed it a little bit so that it compiled without errors, and then I added the last two lines to build a simple matrix, and then output a value, but the "getter" function isn't working for some reason. I adapted the instructions for adding properties found [here](http://nimrod-lang.org/tut2.html#properties), but something isn't right.

Here is my code so far. I'd like to use the GNU Scientific Library from within Nimrod, and I figured that this was the first logical step.

```
type 
  TMatrix*[T] = object
    transposed: bool
    dataRows: int
    dataCols: int
    data: seq[T]

proc index[T](x: TMatrix[T], r,c: int): int {.inline.} = 
  if r<0  or  r>(x.rows()-1):
    raise newException(EInvalidIndex, "matrix index out of range")
  if c<0  or  c>(x.cols()-1):
    raise newException(EInvalidIndex, "matrix index out of range")
  result = if x.transposed: c*x.dataCols+r else: r*x.dataCols+c

proc rows*[T](x: TMatrix[T]): int {.inline.} = 
  ## Returns the number of rows in the matrix `x`.
  result = if x.transposed: x.dataCols else: x.dataRows

proc cols*[T](x: TMatrix[T]): int {.inline.}  = 
  ## Returns the number of columns in the matrix `x`.
  result = if x.transposed: x.dataRows else: x.dataCols

proc matrix*[T](rows, cols: int, d: openarray[T]): TMatrix[T] = 
  ## Constructor.  Initializes the matrix by allocating memory
  ## for the data and setting the number of rows and columns
  ## and sets the data to the values specified in `d`.
  result.dataRows = rows
  result.dataCols = cols
  newSeq(result.data, rows*cols)
  if len(d)>0:
    if len(d)<(rows*cols):
      raise newException(EInvalidIndex, "insufficient data supplied in matrix     constructor")

    for i in countup(0,rows*cols-1):
      result.data[i] = d[i]

proc `[][]`*[T](x: TMatrix[T], r,c: int): T = 
  ## Element access.  Returns the element at row `r` column `c`.
  result = x.data[x.index(r,c)]

proc `[][]=`*[T](x: var TMatrix[T], r,c: int, a: T) = 
  ## Sets the value of the element at row `r` column `c` to
  ## the value supplied in `a`.
  x.data[x.index(r,c)] = a

var m = matrix( 2, 2, [1,2,3,4] )

echo( $m[0][0] )
```

This is the error I get:

```
c:\program files (x86)\nimrod\config\nimrod.cfg(36, 11) Hint: added path:       'C:\Users\H127\.babel\libs\' [Path]
Hint: used config file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nimrod\config\nimrod.cfg' [Conf]
Hint: system [Processing]
Hint: mat [Processing]
mat.nim(48, 9) Error: type mismatch: got (TMatrix[int], int literal(0))
but expected one of: 
system.[](a: array[Idx, T], x: TSlice[Idx]): seq[T]
system.[](a: array[Idx, T], x: TSlice[int]): seq[T]
system.[](s: string, x: TSlice[int]): string
system.[](s: seq[T], x: TSlice[int]): seq[T]
```

Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to first point out that [the matrix library you refer to](https://github.com/twist-vector/matrix) is three years old. For a programming language in development that's a lot of time due to changes, and it doesn't compile any more with the current [Nimrod git version](https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod):

```
$ nimrod c matrix
...
private/tmp/n/matrix/matrix.nim(97, 8) Error: ']' expected
```

It fails on the double array accessor, which seems to have changed syntax. I guess your attempt to create a double `[][]` accessor is problematic, it could be ambiguous: are you accessing the double array accessor of the object or are you accessing the nested array returned by the first brackets? I had to change the `proc` to the following:

```
proc `[]`*[T](x: TMatrix[T], r,c: int): T =
```

After that change you also need to change the way to access the matrix. Here's what I got:

```
for x in 0 .. <2:
  for y in 0 .. <2:
    echo "x: ", x, " y: ", y, " = ", m[x,y]
```

Basically, instead of specifying two bracket accesses you pass all the parameters inside a single bracket. That code generates:

```
x: 0 y: 0 = 1
x: 0 y: 1 = 2
x: 1 y: 0 = 3
x: 1 y: 1 = 4
```

With regards to finding software for Nimrod, I would like to recommend you using [Nimble, Nimrod's package manager](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble). Once you have it installed you can search available and maintained packages. The command `nimble search math` shows two potential packages: [linagl](https://bitbucket.org/BitPuffin/linagl) and [extmath](https://github.com/achesak/extmath.nim). Not sure if they are what you are looking for, but at least they seem more *fresh*.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that it was old, I just took the basics out and tried to fiddle with them. I found extmath, but it didn't have what I needed; I'll definitely look at linalg. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, for completeness, I'll add that the "setter" `proc` needs to be changed to `proc \`[]=\`*[T](x: var TMatrix[T], r,c: int, a: T) = `.